# 3D plot Animation in plotly Python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python, plotly.graph-objects

x1, y1, z1 is 3D numpy array. Need to animate 3D figure in different position.

```
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=[], y=[], z=[],
                         mode="markers",
                         marker=dict(color="red", size=10)
                         )
            ,


    # generating Frames
    frames = [go.Frame(data= [
        
            go.Scatter3d(x=x1[i,k,:],y=y1[i,k,:], z=z1[i,k,:])
                      ],
               traces= [0],
               name=f'frame{i}{k}'      
              )for i in range(10) for k in range(20)    # loop with k generates figure and loop with i generates position
              ]
    )

    def frame_args(duration):
        return {
                "frame": {"duration": duration},
                "mode": "immediate",
                "fromcurrent": True,
                "transition": {"duration": duration, "easing": "linear"},
                }

    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus = [{"buttons":[
                        {
                            "args": [None, frame_args(50)],
                            "label": "Play", 
                            "method": "animate",
                        },
                        {
                            "args": [[None], frame_args(0)],
                            "label": "Pause", 
                            "method": "animate",
                    }],
                
                    "direction": "left",
                    "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 70},
                    "type": "buttons",
                    "x": 0.1,
                    "y": 0,
                }
            ],
            
        )


    fig.show()
```

This is not giving a right figure. How it should be approached?

first loop generates this figure: need to animate below figure at different positions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXEpF.png)